# Convert scroll view frame to window coordinates

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am trying to convert scroll view coordinates to window coordinates. However the resulting frame seems to be shifted by status bar height, what's confusing is that the height remains the same which is not right.

```
CGRect visibleBounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, CGRectGetWidth(self.scrollView.frame), CGRectGetHeight(self.scrollView.frame));

CGRect scrollViewFrame = [self.scrollView convertRect:visibleBounds toView:nil];
```

lldb log:

> Printing description of visibleBounds: (CGRect) visibleBounds =
>   (origin = (x = 0, y = 0), size = (width = 320, height = 568))
>
> Printing description of scrollViewFrame: (CGRect) scrollViewFrame = (origin =
>   (x = 0, y = 20), size = (width = 320, height = 568))

Comment: are u expecting scrollview height to be changed with scroll ?

Comment: are you looking for  scrollView.contentSize.height ? or scrollview height ?

Comment: bounds always start with 0,0...and frame always starts from 0,0 starting from the status bar!!! the height is still the same in both cases

Comment: @Mr.T Scroll view should not start below status bar because it is placed behind it.

Comment: the values u see in the log are correct!!!! could u pls provide the expected result too ?

Comment: @Mr.T nope they are not correct. My scroll view has the following coordinates: {0,0,320,568}. This is the coordinates within the window. I can confirm that by inspecting UI in debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out scroll view bounds can be used to calculate the frame for scroll view in window coordinates, regardless the fact that I see negative bounds, produced frame will be correct anyway.

```
[self.scrollView convertRect:self.scrollView.bounds toView:nil];
```